# How to use multiple with statements along with UNION ALL in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

```
WITH L1 AS
(
   SELECT
)
SELECT A FROM L1

UNION ALL

SELECT A FROM TABLE

UNION ALL

WITH L2 AS
(
   SELECT
)
SELECT A FROM L2

UNION ALL

WITH L3 AS
(
   SELECT
)
SELECT A FROM L3
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Please help

Comment: You don't need the WITH AS clauses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is

```
With l1 ( a ) as ( Select ... )
   , l2 ( a ) as ( ... )
  Select ... From ...
  Union
  Select ... From ...
```

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use `WITH` in the *middle* of a query expression.  `WITH` is used to build up intermediate queries for use by other queries immediately after (meaning it cannot be used by multiple independent queries).

So you probably want something like:

```
WITH L1 
AS
(
    SELECT ...
),
L2 AS
(
    SELECT ...
),
L3 AS
(
    SELECT ...
)

// begin final query    
SELECT A FROM L1
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM L2
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM L3
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to do this:

```
SELECT A FROM L1
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM L2
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM L3
```

OR

```
WITH CTE_L AS
(
    SELECT A FROM L1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A FROM L2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A FROM L3
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_L
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this answer makes no sense.